# iOS/Swift: tabBarController instance

Tags: ios, swift, tabbarcontroller

I have the following code, which works fine:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let barViewControllers = segue.destination as! UITabBarController
        let nav = barViewControllers.viewControllers![0] as! UINavigationController
        let mainVC = nav.viewControllers[0] as! MainForecastViewController
        if let lat = Double(latitudeTextField.text!) {
            mainVC.latPassed = lat
        }

        if let lng = Double(longitudeTextField.text!) {
            mainVC.LongPassed = lng
        }
    }
```

The problem is, this creates a new instance of UITabBarController while there is already one. 
I tried:

```
    tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
    let mainVC = segue.destination as! MainForecastViewController
    if let lat = Double(latitudeTextField.text!) {
       mainVC.latPassed = lat
    }

    if let lng = Double(longitudeTextField.text!) {
       mainVC.LongPassed = lng
    }
```

it switches to the destination controller, but does not pass data.
The segue is from this controller (LocationChangeViewController) to the tabBarController `performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueToMain", sender: self)`

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is yours `segue.destination` view controller? Is it Tab Bar Controller or `MainForecastViewController`?

Comment: Your code works fine in my quick test... Try using `mainVC.latPassed = 1.0` to confirm that is actually being called. You should also use `if let` for your `barViewControllers =`, `nav =` and `mainVC =` to make sure you're getting what you expect.

Comment: @VladislavKovalyov Segue is set to Tab Bar Controller

Comment: @DonMag mainVC.latPassed = 1.0 is not working either. It takes me back to the MainForecastViewController and does not pass the latitude and longitude.

Comment: @RochNoure - does it take you to `MainForecastViewController` only? Or does it take you to the `UITabBarController` with `MainForecastViewController` showing?

Comment: @RochNoure - ah, your question is confusing... You are already in a Tab of a TabBarController? Where are you trying to segue to? A different tab? Or you're segueing to a new VC, replacing the current Tab? Or, you're current Tab contains a NavController, and you're trying to segue (push) to a new VC in that NavController?

Comment: I am segueing to MainForecastViewController through tabBar and nav controller. Hence, UITabBarController -> UINavigationController -> MainForecastViewController. The code works fine, no issues except that it creates a new instance of the UITaBBatController, which I'm trying to avoid, that's why I'm trying to implement     tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0 instead of let barViewControllers = segue.destination as! UITabBarController.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a Segue to move from one tab to another.

Assuming you want to go from `SecondTabViewController` to `MainForecastViewController` due to a button tap (or some other user action), use this in `SecondTabViewController`:

```
@IBAction func didTap(_ sender: Any) {
    if let tabVC = self.tabBarController {
        if let tabVCControllers = tabVC.viewControllers {
            if let navVC = tabVCControllers[0] as? UINavigationController {
                if let mainVC = navVC.viewControllers[0] as? MainForecastViewController {

                    if let lat = Double(latitudeTextField.text!) {
                        mainVC.latPassed = lat
                    }

                    if let lng = Double(longitudeTextField.text!) {
                        mainVC.LongPassed = lng
                    }

                    tabVC.selectedIndex = 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an example project demonstrating the process: https://github.com/DonMag/TabData

Comment: I tried this, thank you by the way, but it does not pass the latitude and longitude. I get no errors, it just switches back to the target view controller and shows the default location. How come it works fine with: `let barViewControllers = segue.destination as! UITabBarController
        let nav = barViewControllers.viewControllers![0] as! UINavigationController
        let mainVC = nav.viewControllers[0] as! MainForecastViewController`

Comment: @RochNoure - I edited my answer to include a link to a GitHub project.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much!